# Fastest way to push huge array of integers to browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, compression

I have typed array of integers on a server side in node.js (e.g. Uint32Array) with more then 20 million elements. I need to send this data to browser. What kind of compression is better to use? My array is a concatenation of sorted arrays and I suppose it's easy to compress.

Comment: What is browser expected to do with array when received? _"send this data to browser"_ Do you mean browser requests data?

Comment: I don't know the kind of concatenation you're using, or if the sorted integers are sequential. Let's assume the worst case, that the sorted integers aren't sequential and don't follow any progression (i.e. they're random and monotonically increasing) - GZip aside, this is a hard problem both in terms of the network transfer and the browser memory it's going to occupy. Maybe you can share some more information on what it is that the 20 million integers will accomplish in the browser? Of if there are patterns / progressions in your data to represent it in a formulaic form?

Comment: This is a peace of my data stored in PNG - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxNwHJ5sEARBVDByRHBzamFzLW8/view

Comment: I'm playing with array buffer and png encoders, and I achieve compression from 6.4Mb of raw data to 1.5Mb. 
May be some solutions or library already exists for this tasks...

Comment: This looks quite well filterable with simple delta encoding